# .NET Push-Notifications Arcitecture

Tags: .net, web-services, azure, architecture, push-notification

We are trying to build the below service with .NET technologies and Azure.
I'd like hear your suggestions about what kind of architecture should we follow. Should we go with .NET Web API or better with WCF? Also where should i look in Azure for push notifications?

Here is the application concept:

A mobile client creates an event and adds 4 recipients for this event, then it sends these data to the web-service (hosted in Azure) where the web-service sends the event to the first recipient which is also a mobile user (Android, iOS, WP etc).

If the 1st recipient don't accept the event in 20 minutes then the server sends the event to the 2nd recipient.

This continues until a recipient accepts the event or there are no more recipients for the event.

I have zero experience with push notifications so it would be great to point me to a direction to look. Also if you think it can be done in another way easier without .NET or Azure i'm also happy to listen.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: PushSharp https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp.  That's what you need :) EDIT: It works fine!!!

Comment: Kostas thanks it looks really promising. Just one more question if i understood correctly I need to keep in my database the platform (Android, iOS , WP etc) that each user is on so i can create the appropriate PushService for each user correct?

Comment: It is very good. I am using it since 2013 and i am sending (android) 1000 notifications/day with no problem! You need just to keep the code that google will give you when you ask with project_id where you have first create in your google development account. If the the user is off, will get the message when is on.

Answer (score 0):

for push notifications you need tokens for each device you need to send notification to.
which  needs to go in your database.

pushsharp is good way to do it.. your database must store all related information.

I have used it for apple in the past and it worked very well from azure worker roles sending out notifications 1000's simultaneously..